# Using MDCAppBarNavigationController with storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, mdc-components

I'm trying to add the MDC App bar to my app as defined by MaterialComponents' custom subclass of `UINavigationController`. I go by the terse description on their [Github page](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/AppBar#typical-use-view-controller-containment-as-a-navigation-controller):

> The easiest integration path for using the app bar is through the MDCAppBarNavigationController. This API is a subclass of UINavigationController that automatically adds an MDCAppBarViewController instance to each view controller that is pushed onto it, unless an app bar or flexible header already exists.
>
> When using the MDCAppBarNavigationController you will, at a minimum, need to configure the added app bar's background color using the delegate.
>
> ```
> navigationController.pushViewController(<#T##viewController: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>)
>
> // MARK: MDCAppBarNavigationControllerDelegate
>
> func appBarNavigationController(_ navigationController: MDCAppBarNavigationController,
>                                 willAdd appBarViewController: MDCAppBarViewController,
>                                 asChildOf viewController: UIViewController) {
>   appBarViewController.headerView.backgroundColor = <#(UIColor)#>
> }
> ```

In my storyboard, I've added a `UINavigationController` and I've set its identity to `MDCAppBarNavigationController` in the identity inspector.

In my root view controller, I implement `MDCAppBarNavigationControllerDelegate`:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "My app"
    if let nav = navigationController as? MDCAppBarNavigationController {
      print("[MyViewController] Setting delegate MDCAppBarNavigationControllerDelegate")
      nav.delegate = self
    }
  }

  // MARK: MDCAppBarNavigationControllerDelegate
  func appBarNavigationController(_ navigationController: MDCAppBarNavigationController,
                                    willAdd appBarViewController: MDCAppBarViewController,
                                    asChildOf viewController: UIViewController) {
      print("Setting app bar color")
      appBarViewController.headerView.backgroundColor = .red
  }
}
```

When I run the app, I see an ordinary navigation bar and the delegate method is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After different tries I made it working by creating a custom `MDCAppBarNavigationController` and set it to my `UINavigationController` in the Storyboard (Identity tab -> Class)

Here's my custom MDCAppBarNavigationController:

```
import MaterialComponents.MDCAppBarNavigationController

class MaterialNavigationController: MDCAppBarNavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
    }
}

extension MaterialNavigationController: MDCAppBarNavigationControllerDelegate {
  func appBarNavigationController(_ navigationController: MDCAppBarNavigationController, willAdd appBarViewController: MDCAppBarViewController, asChildOf viewController: UIViewController) {

    appBarViewController.applyTheme()
    appBarViewController.navigationBar.applyTheme()
  }
}
```